# how to save out the column and row value in which the maximum occurs in sas

Tags: sas, max

I need to find the row and column that the maximum occurs in a lower triangle covariance matrix.  Then I can replace that entire row and column with missing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please add a small example data set to illustrate exactly what you want done.  A before and after image would help.

Comment: Are you using SAS-IML, or just base SAS?

Comment: When you say row and column, do you mean finding the singular intersection of both where the highest value occurs, or do you mean figuring out independently which row has the highest value and which column has the highest value (out of all rows, or all columns, respectively)?

Comment: Also, I need the row and column where the maximum of the matrix occurs.

Comment: So, yes it needs to be out of all rows and all columns.  I can then replace the entire row and column with 0s or a large negative number and repeat the function.

Comment: In basic, I would do max and loop over the rows, and the columns...let me see if I can come up with some simple data for you.

Comment: @TylerHunt OK, check out that and tell me if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option to do this - I would suggest that R might make it easier, but in SAS, this will work (not IML - I don't know about IML personally).

First, create a hypothetical triangular matrix.

```
DATA test;
    INPUT v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7;
    DATALINES;
    0.13 . . . . . .
    0.21 0.30 . . . . .
    0.31 0.52 0.79 . . . .
    0.05 0.11 0.25 0.18 . . .
    0.77 0.93 0.81 0.51 0.02 . .
    0.96 0.09 0.45 0.36 0.14 0.29 .
    0.55 0.67 0.71 0.92 0.44 0.38 0.01
RUN;
```

Get the maximums in each row:

```
DATA test;
    SET test;
    rowmax = max(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7);
RUN;
```

Then, transpose the dataset:

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=test OUT=test PREFIX=v;
RUN;
```

Now, get the column maximums:

```
DATA test;
    SET test;
    colmax = max(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7);
RUN;
```

Fix it back to original orientation:

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=test OUT=test;
    ID _NAME_;
RUN;
```

Finally, delete an unnecessary value:

```
DATA test;
    SET test;
    IF _N_=8 THEN rowmax=.;
RUN;
```

And print for showing the data structure:

```
PROC PRINT DATA=test;
RUN;
```

This gives you the following output:

```
_NAME_     v1      v2      v3      v4      v5      v6      v7     rowmax
 v1        0.13     .       .       .       .       .       .       0.13
 v2        0.21    0.30     .       .       .       .       .       0.30
 v3        0.31    0.52    0.79     .       .       .       .       0.79
 v4        0.05    0.11    0.25    0.18     .       .       .       0.25
 v5        0.77    0.93    0.81    0.51    0.02     .       .       0.93
 v6        0.96    0.09    0.45    0.36    0.14    0.29     .       0.96
 v7        0.55    0.67    0.71    0.92    0.44    0.38    0.01     0.92
 colmax    0.96    0.93    0.81    0.92    0.44    0.38    0.01      .
```

The only remaining part is the logic (so, which of the 7 columns contain the biggest value among all columns, and which of the 7 rows contain the biggest value among all rows). Then, you can do this. Start with figuring out which column to zerofill:

```
DATA test;
    SET test;
    index=_N_;
    ARRAY v v1-v7;
    IF _N_=8 THEN DO i=1 TO 7;
        IF v[i]=max(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7) THEN DO;
            CALL SYMPUT('rightcol',i);
        END;
    END;
    IF _N_~=8 THEN v["&rightcol"]=0;
    DROP i;
RUN;
```

Now, to get the row, just sort the dataset (that's why I set an index up above).

```
PROC SORT DATA=test;
    BY DESCENDING rowmax;
RUN;
```

Now, you can zero-fill across that row by just doing the operation where *N*=1.

```
DATA test;
    SET test;
    ARRAY v v1-v7;
    IF _N_=1 THEN DO i=1 TO 7;
        v[i]=0;
    END;
    DROP i;
RUN;
```

And re-sort the set:

```
PROC SORT DATA=test;
    BY index;
RUN;
```

And you end up with this output:

```
_NAME_     v1      v2      v3      v4      v5      v6      v7     rowmax    index
v1        0.00     .       .       .       .       .       .       0.13       1
v2        0.00    0.30     .       .       .       .       .       0.30       2
v3        0.00    0.52    0.79     .       .       .       .       0.79       3
v4        0.00    0.11    0.25    0.18     .       .       .       0.25       4
v5        0.00    0.93    0.81    0.51    0.02     .       .       0.93       5
v6        0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.96       6
v7        0.00    0.67    0.71    0.92    0.44    0.38    0.01     0.92       7
colmax    0.96    0.93    0.81    0.92    0.44    0.38    0.01      .         8
```

If you need to iterate, just tweak the code to wipe the values in colmax and rowmax.

Comment: This is great but I really need the column and row to calculate the statistic and also I will then be able to enter the column and row values into a matrix command like:   

`sigma_split[row,column]=0`

Where sigma_split is the matrix that I am trying to find where the maximum occurs.  Also, I agree with you that this is much easier in R.  The code in R that parallels what I want is this

 `x.m<-which(sigma.split==max(sigma-split),arr.ind=TRUE)`

Comment: You might be able to use a multidimensional array to accomplish this. I'm a bit rusty on my SAS skills and right now I'm slammed at work, but if I have a chance I'll see if I can mess with it...